# How to get credentials in Google AppEngine Python37

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I started new app in AppEngine Python3.7 stadard.

I am trying to get credentials using the following snippet, but its failing.

Anybody able to get `credentials` in GAE standard Python37 ?

Input:

```
from google.auth import app_engine
credentials = app_engine.Credentials()
```

Output:

```
The App Engine APIs are not available
```

Comment: Dan, GAE Standard now has Python 3.7 available!

Comment: @GAEfan - OK, good to know :)

Comment: @snakecharmerb I am trying to access google cloud build API from GAE py37

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using App Engine Standard with python 3.7, none of the google.xxx libraries are available.  You have to build your own, or use standard Python libraries.  This goes for: `auth`, `users`, `images`, `search`, `mail`, `taskqueue`, `memcache`, `urlfetch`, `deferred`, etc., and even the `ndb` datastore interface.

For datastore, you use `google-cloud-datastore` or some 3rd party.

For others, you use a standard Python library, e.g.: `google.auth` => `rauth`, `google.appengine.api.memcache`  => `python-memcached`

Read more here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences

That page recommends Google Identity Platform or Firebase Authentication to do authorization.

Comment: Yep, significant differences than with python 2.7. [This guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences) would be a good starting point.

Comment: Yes.  Added to answer.

Comment: @GAEfan, Thanks for your answer. I hope GCP provide these features natively in future.

Comment: Yeah, me too!  Also, 3.7 seems very slow.  It takes ~8 secs to spin up a new instance.  Not acceptable for a production site, IMO.

Comment: More libraries for 3.7: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python