# AppEngine doesn't recognize built-in third party libraries

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

My AppEngine environment doesn't recognize any of the preinstalled modules that it's supposed to. I've tried manually pip installing them, pip updating them, adding them to the libraries section of the app.yaml file, creating an appengine_config file, and nothing has worked. I just get an error along the lines of "ImportError: No module named jinja2.environment" for example.

Comment: Python 2.7 or 3.7?  Could be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799366/how-to-get-credentials-in-google-appengine-python37/51801781#51801781  PIP installing into a lib directory should fix that.

Comment: Python 2.7. I tried pip installing it into a lib directory too. At this point I feel like I should just reinstall AppEngine completely.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503620/dev-appserver-py-app-yaml-produces-importerror-importing-the-multiarray-numpy/52520995#52520995

Answer (score 1):

`jinja2` is a built-in 3rd party library in GAE Std.  In `app.yaml`, have:

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

Then, in your `views.py`, import directly:

```
from jinja2 import ...
```

To avoid confusion and conflicts, do not pip install them into a `lib` directory..  You can delete them if you did.