# How can an authentication token be obtained from the Google App Engine (standard environment) with Python 3?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-authentication, google-app-engine-python

I need to delete a BigQuery table partition using a Python 3 app running on the App Engine in the standard environment. It appears that the way to do this is through an HTTPS call, with an authentication token: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/delete

https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html explains how to create credentials for the App Engine:

```
from google.auth import app_engine
credentials = app_engine.Credentials()
```

But as reported and explained in [GCP-The App Engine APIs are not available, with py 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039984/gcp-the-app-engine-apis-are-not-available-with-py-3) and [How to get credentials in Google AppEngine Python37](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799366/how-to-get-credentials-in-google-appengine-python37/51801781) , trying to access app_engine in the Python 3 standard environment results in the following error

```
The App Engine APIs are not available
```

since the python37 runtime doesn't include proprietary app engine APIs such as the App Identity API.

Is there any way in which I can obtain a token from the App Engine for use with the HTTPS call to BigQuery? Or can a BigQuery partition be deleted by another means?

Comment: In here (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#deleting_tables) you can see the ways to delete a table, might help you in case you would prefer other methods.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan Neascu. Since the problem is to do with deleting a partition in a partitioned table, rather than deleting the table itself, the only option seems to be the command line tool's `bq rm` command or an HTTP(S) call with the tables.delete API method: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables . Since your suggestion, I've tried running the `bq` command in a sub-process, but unfortunately `bq` doesn't seem to be available when running the Python code as a service on the App engine.

Comment: See [this](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58992933/11135166), and [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/access-control#apps). I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks @asbovelw. Your first link made me have a closer look at the google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client code. I found there was a protected member called _credentials, so client._credentials.token gave me the token I needed and the partition deletion request worked :-) . This avoided having to generate and store a JSON key file as per your third link. A downside though with the client._credentials.token approach is accessing a protected member rather than a public interface, so there is a risk that future changes to the bq library might stop it working. However, it works for now. Many thanks.